# xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies requires authentication

Tags: authentication, github-actions, xcodebuild

I use xcodebuild in my CI/CD pipeline and have to resolve dependencies from package manager first. My builds fails, because the build machine can't resolve authentication data. How can I set this?

It works on my local machine, but fails on remote Mac. I have a Github-Token but do not know how to set it it.

```
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub actions you can set it up using this step

```
- name: Configure git
  env:
    TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SPM_CI }}
  run: git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```